# Running elif statements through a table or URLs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I am attempting to see which sharepoint sites are active by pulling the html status code from a table of urls. When I try to apply the elif statement to each row I receive an "Invalid URL 'False': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://False?" message. I'm wondering what's off in my code that's causing the error. I tested the code initially with a single url to verify that the elif statements were running properly.

I've tested with individual URLs, but I'm having difficulty getting the code to look at each row in the dataframe.

confirmation = []

```
for row in df['2010 Site']:
    url = row in df['2010 Site']
    r = requests.head(url)
    if r.status_code == 401:
        print ('web site exists, permission needed')
    else:
        print('other')
```

"Invalid URL 'False': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://False?" when i would like it to return the print statement in the elif statements

SAMPLE OF CODE WITHOUT REFERENCING THE DATAFRAME:

```
url = 'http://sp-stam1/MCS'
r = requests.head(url)
if r.status_code == 401:
    print ('web site exists, permission needed')
else:
    print('other')
```

result: 'web site exists, permission needed'

Comment: Have you tried printing `url` and `r` variables to debug? What are the values?

Comment: Try removing `url = row in df['2010 Site']` and place row instead of url in  `r= requests.head(url)`

Comment: Thank you, Prasad! That did the trick, I really appreciate it

Comment: Great!  I'm adding comment as answer! Please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `url = row in df['2010 Site']` and place row instead of url in `r= requests.head(url)`